# comparing 2d char array against 1d char array in c

Tags: c, arrays, char

I want to compare the second element of array against string to see if they match. I am trying to use memcmp to do this but it gives me an error. Is this the correct way of approaching this, or am I complete off? I'm sorry, I'm new to C.

```
char array[5][32] = {"foo","boo","moo"};
char string[32] = "boo";
int ret;
ret = memcmp(array[1][32], string[32], 4) //4 because i don't want it too match 'book'
if (ret == 0) {
     printf("equal");
} else {
     printf("not");
}
```

Comment: Lose the [32] on both arguments to `memcmp`. That is dereferencing the last character in the C string.

Comment: instead of pointing to the 32th byte of your array, point to the first like this: `ret = memcmp(array[1][0], string[0], 4)`

Comment: `strcmp(array[1], string)` would seem more appropriate.

Comment: What compiler are you using?  Certainly it is generating warnings that you are ignoring.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should compare them from the starting address. Change it to

```
ret = memcmp(&array[1][0], &string[0], 4);
```

or simply

```
ret = memcmp(array[1], string, 4);
```

or better (as suggested by @Darren), no need to give the length

```
ret = strcmp(array[1], string);
```

Comment: Or `strcmp` (and no length argument).  The `4` is a liability if your string length ever changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare entire strings then it is better to use standard function `strcmp` If you want to compare substrings then you need to use function `memcmp`.

In your program it is obvious that it is better to use function `strcmp` because you are trying to compare also the terminating zero
The comparison will look like

```
ret = strcmp( array[1], string );

if ( ret == 0) {
     printf("equal\n");
} else {
     printf("not equal\n");
}
```

As for your code then expression array[1][32] is a single character. It is not a string.

If you want to compare whether there is a string in the two dimensional array  that starts with "boo"; then you indeed should use function `memcmp`. In this case the correct code will look like

```
ret = memcmp( array[1], string, strlen( string ) );

if ( ret == 0) {
     printf("equal\n");
} else {
     printf("not equal\n");
}
```

Comment: strcmp and memcmp, not strcpy and memcpy.

Comment: @Jonathon Reinhart Thanks. Everybody can make a typo, I only wonder who is that idiot who down-voted my answer.

Comment: I was that idiot, and I removed it, realizing that it was a typo.

Comment: @Jonathon Reinhart Ok, I hope the question has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the 'strcmp' function this way:

```
if ( strcmp( array[1], string ) == 0 ) {
  printf("equal\n");
}
else {
  printf("not equal\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to compare *up to* a certain length in your string, use [strncmp](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strncmp.html).

```
strncmp(array[1], string, 3)
```